# Remove whitespace from list of strings with pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which one columns values are lists of strings.
here the structure of the file to read:

```
[
    {
        "key1":"value1 ",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":["a","b  2 "," exp  white   space 210"],
    },
    {
        "key1":"value1 ",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":[],
    },

]
```

I need to remove all white space for each item if it is more than one white space.
expected output:

```
[
    {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":["a","b2","exp white space 210"],
    },
    {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"2",
        "key3":[],
    }
]
```

**Note:**
I have some value that are empty in some lines e.g `"key3":[]`

Comment: Use `df.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)` for multiple spaces and use `str.strip` for the leading and trailing spaces

Comment: This is not working with the value in the array

Comment: It does work. I tested it.

Comment: Please change the question to put a sample problematic input, i.e., your empty list. People should be able to cut and paste your sample and reproduce the actual problem you're struggling with.

Comment: It is not a valid json after the change in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly some of your dataframe cells have `list type` values.

The `file_name.json` content is below:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value1 ",
        "key2": "2",
        "key3": ["a", "b  2 ", " exp  white   space 210"]
    }, 
    {
        "key1": "value1 ",
        "key2": "2",
        "key3": []
    }
]
```

**Possible solution in this case is the following:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_json("file_name.json")


def cleanup_data(value):
    if value and type(value) is list:
        return [re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', x.strip()) for x in value]
    elif value and type(value) is str:
        return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', value.strip())
    else:
        return value

# apply cleanup function to all cells in dataframe
df = df.applymap(cleanup_data)

df
```

Returns

```
     key1  key2                           key3
0  value1     2  [a, b 2, exp white space 210]
1  value1     2                             []
```

Comment: I have an array of object, so this will not work

Comment: I updated the code to the new format of input data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
df = pd.read_json('''{
    "key1":"value1 ",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":["a","b   "," exp  white   space "],
    "key2":" value2"
}''')

df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip().str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     key1    key2             key3
0  value1  value2                a
1  value1  value2                b
2  value1  value2  exp white space

>>> df.to_numpy()
array([['value1', 'value2', 'a'],
       ['value1', 'value2', 'b'],
       ['value1', 'value2', 'exp white space']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!.`

Comment: Will you please provide how you're reading the JSON file in the question? I think we're reading it differently, thus the error and your end and not on mine :)

Comment: `df = pd.read_json("filename.json")`

Comment: When I paste your JSON into `filename.json`, run `df = pd.read_json("filename.json")` and then `df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip().str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True))`, it produces a dataframe just like the one in my answer. So I can't tell what's wrong...

Comment: I guess because that i have some value that are empty in some lines e.g `"key3":[]`